# How to Generate Nakagami–m Fading Channel on MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, networking, communication, labview, fading

How to Generate Nakagami–m Fading Channel on MATLAB? similar to Figure 4 in the paper "Overview of Fading Channel Modeling" by Krystyna M. Noga and Beata Palczynska. Here is the link of the paper
https://www.researchgate.net/publication/270255881_Overview_of_Fading_Channel_Modeling

I need a code or steps to generate Nakagami–m fading channel on MATLAB similar to Figure 4.

Comment: Hi, Welcome to StackOverflow. Your question is open and not very specific. What have you tried so far regarding the plot?

Comment: Is your question about how to calculate the data for the plot shown in that figure, or just how to create a LabVIEW front panel looking like that? If it's the calculation, you'll have to work carefully through the paper and reproduce their maths with your own code. Or you could try contacting the authors to see if their code is available, although the paper is ten years old so they may have moved institutions, no longer have it etc.